# Image address issue ASP.Net 4.5 web form

Tags: asp.net

I have an Images folder with 3 images. I included them in the project.

[image]

Here's is the default.aspx file with the reference to the image(s).

[image]

When I run the app on the localhost the images do not appear.

[image]

I right click an image and select "open image in a new tab".

[image]

The physical address does not include the Images folder.

How is this address set? 
Why does it not recognize the Images folder?
How do I path it to the Images folder?

To get the images to appear, I had to copy the 3 images to the root and include them in the project. Why?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a question of what is output for `Eval("ProductImage")`. If it is simply `Dell.jpg`, then that image must be in the same directory as the page; `Dell.jpg` is not saying "I'm in another folder," it's saying "I'm in the current folder, the same one as this page I'm on."

Hopefully you just need to adjust the link to something like this

```
ImageUrl='<% "~/images/" + Eval("ProductImage") %>'
```

(I hope I got the syntax right.)

Another way (prob better)

```
ImageUrl='<% string.Format("~/images/{0}", Eval("ProductImage")) %>'
```

Comment: Just needed the # sign. <%#string.Format("~/Images/{0}", Eval("ProductImage"))%>   All good. Thanks.